# How to remove Static Scaffold content

Tags: grails, scaffolding

Is there a better, or proper way to remove the output of a `$ grails generate-all Tip` above simply running a rm on the TipController and on the views/tip dir?

Comment: why do you generate if you don't want it?

Comment: I absolutely wanted the scaffold views and controllers but I needed to remove them and then test something with Dynamic Scaffolding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually removing the files as you suggested is the proper way to remove the generated content. There is no built in grails command to do so.